# What does the percentage refer to when used as coordinate values?

Tags: html, css

I found some sample code to solve a previous problem I was looking at but do not fully understand the solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}


/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: none;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p><b>Note:</b> This example does not work in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is some sample code that will pull  the image from the left and show it over the duration of four seconds. However I do not understand the percentages used in this example, specifically `transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);`

When percentages are used in this context, or however any. What is it referring to? -100% of what? I understand that sometimes `height: 50%;` will set the height to 50% of the current width, however this example seems different.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `translate3D()` which is a CSS method to move the object in terms of the 3 planes, x, y, and z with the syntax `translate3d(tx, ty, tz)`. You can look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate3d) which goes into more detail.

Answer (score 1):

`translate3D(tx, ty, tz)` is a CSS method to move the object in terms of the 3 cartesian planes, x, y, and z. When your `transform` property is set to `-100%`, the object is moved 100% relatively in the opposite direction in the x plane.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a peek at [the documentation for `translate3d`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate3d), the first variable is `tx`.

> ***tx*** is a length or percentage representing the abscissa of the translating vector.

According to Wikipedia, the abscissa "is the distance between the projection and the origin of the axis".

So from this, we can surmise that the percentage here is relative to the width of the shape you are using `translate` on.

If you have a 100px wide shape, translate3d(100%, 0, 0) will move it to the right by 100px.

> When percentages are used in this context, or however any. What is it referring to? -100% of what? I understand that sometimes height: 50%; will set the height to 50% of the current width, however this example seems different.

You are absolutely right! Percentages usually are relative to the parent. This specific case is different. [According to the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/percentage):

> The percentage CSS data type represents a percentage value. It is often used to define a size as relative to an element's parent object.

---

**Further Reading**

[Here's a great article on CSS](https://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/getting-to-know-css) you might be interested in.

Specifically, 2/3 of the way down the page, there's a heading title "Lengths" that you may find very helpful with clarifying your understanding on absolute units like `px` vs. relative units like percentages.

Answer (score 1):

It is relative to the [bounding box](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/coords.html#TermObjectBoundingBox) which is defined as

> The object bounding box is the bounding box that contains only an element's geometric shape. For basic shapes, this is the area that is filled. Unless otherwise specified, this is what is meant by the unqualified term "bounding box".

Since the parameters of translate3d are the x,y and z coordinates, the -100% applied in your example to the x coordinate will move it left by 100% with respect to it's bounding box.